# How to fix glitch in onEdit() time stamp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have a simple time stamping script exactly as shown below.
As entries are made in column B the script will do it's magic and place a time and date stamp in column A.

I'm having some glitch problems.
I have 8 employees and myself registering on this sheet at once. Sometimes the time stamp does not work and Leaves Column A empty.
I thought the script was running slow and tested by registering slowly. (1-2 Seconds between each registries.)
BUT it still leaves some empty.
I cannot share the original file since it is in closed network.

I have about 5 scripts on this file, all time stamps. Does it glitch because I have too many scripts? What am I doing wrong here?

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Бүх Бүртгэл" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the operating conditions when timestamps are missed? (One user, multiple users?) Does the problem show up for some types of users more than others? (Owner / editor / reader) Are the other scripts also `onEdit()` triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Theoretical explanation

An `onEdit()` simple trigger is invoked in response to a spreadsheet edit event, and is associated with a specific User Interface instance. Because it's also a bound script, it has access to information from the associated UI, through methods like `Sheet.getActiveCell()`. In the original script you've shared, that method is being used to determine what cell has been edited, however *that method reports where the cursor currently is*, which is not necessarily the cell that has just been edited. There are ample opportunities for delays between detection of an edit, generation of an event, invocation of the trigger function. If there are multiple users sharing a sheet, synchronization of their copies can also delay invocation of trigger functions. As the possibility and potential duration of delays increases, so does the likelihood that the user whose action triggered the function will have moved on to a different cell, causing the exit conditions in the `onEdit()` function to bypass writing of a timestamp.

#### What to do about it?

Your `onEdit()` trigger function is called in response to an edit event, and the details of that event are delivered to the trigger function as an [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). Instead of calling SpreadsheetApp methods to access the current cursor location, use this event object; it's both faster and less susceptible to changes due to processing delays. Most importantly, since it contains information about the actual edit event, it has no dependence on what the user has done in the mean time.

Here, I've reorganized your trigger function to use the event object AND to be more efficient because it tests "cheap" conditions first, leaving "expensive" service calls until later.

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var r = event.range;
  if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
    var s = r.getSheet();
    if( s.getName() == "Бүх Бүртгэл" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That solved it. Very thorough explanation. Thank you